# How to replace old geometry with new geometry in localStorage using Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, local-storage

I have 2 data layers on my Google Map: `savedLayer` (used for displaying/loading saved data on the map), and `drawLayer` (used for drawing on the map).

I'm currently able to store a drawn polygon on the map in localStorage using the Save button, and then display it on the map from localStorage.

What I'm struggling with is updating localStorage with any changes that are made to a particular polygon afterwards. Let's say you draw 3 or 4 polygons (I assign unique IDs to them). How do I update the geometry in localStorage for the selected polygon? How do I remove it? I basically want to send new updates of that polygon to localStorage once Saved is clicked.

I know there's a `setgeometry` event that I can use, and I'm currently using that to detect when the a geometry in `savedLayer` changes, but am struggling with replacing the old geometry with the new one:

```
changedGeom = savedLayer.addListener('setgeometry', function(e) {
    console.log('changed geometry for polygon #' + e.feature.getProperty('featureID'));
    console.log(e.newGeometry);
});
```

**JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/h0f3ycf4**

P.S. You can currently delete/remove polygons from map using right-click on your mouse. But once I hit Save, this change is not reflected in localStorage.

**Full JS:**

```
var map, data, drawLayer, savedLayer, changedGeom;
var currentID = 0;
var uniqueID = function() {
    return ++currentID;
}

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
            lat: -33.865143,
            lng: 151.209900
        },
        zoom: 16,
        clickableIcons: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
        mapTypeControl: false
    });

    drawLayer = new google.maps.Data({
        map: map
    });
    savedLayer = new google.maps.Data({
        map: map
    });
    drawLayer.setControls(['Polygon']);
    drawLayer.setStyle({
        editable: true,
        draggable: true
    });
    bindDataLayerListeners(drawLayer);
    savePolygons(drawLayer);
    loadPolygons(savedLayer);
}

function bindDataLayerListeners(drawLayer) {
    drawLayer.addListener('addfeature', function(e) {
        e.feature.setProperty('featureID', uniqueID());
    });

    drawLayer.addListener('mouseover', function(e) {
        drawLayer.revertStyle();
        drawLayer.overrideStyle(e.feature, {
            fillOpacity: 0.5,
            editable: true,
            draggable: true
        });
    });
}

function loadPolygons(map) {
    data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('geoData'));

    savedLayer.forEach(function(f) {
        savedLayer.remove(f);
    });

    savedLayer.addGeoJson(data);

    savedLayer.addListener('mouseover', function(e) {
        savedLayer.revertStyle();
        savedLayer.overrideStyle(e.feature, {
            fillOpacity: 0.5,
            editable: true,
            draggable: true
        });
    });

    map.addListener('click', function() {
        savedLayer.revertStyle();
    });

    savedLayer.addListener('rightclick', function(e) {
        data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('geoData'));
        data.features = data.features.filter(function(feature) {
            return feature.properties.featureID !== e.feature.getProperty('featureID');
        });
        savedLayer.remove(e.feature);
    });

    changedGeom = savedLayer.addListener('setgeometry', function(e) {
        console.log('changed geometry for polygon #' + e.feature.getProperty('featureID'));
        console.log(e.newGeometry);
    });
}

function savePolygons(json) {
    var btn = document.getElementById('save-edits');
    btn.onclick = function() {
        // if (changedGeom) {
        // console.log('geometry was changed and updated');
        //savedLayer.addListener('setgeometry', savePolygon);
        // } else {
        // if (json.features.length === 0) {
        // console.log('nothing to save');
        // } else {
        drawLayer.toGeoJson(function(json) {
            localStorage.setItem('geoData', JSON.stringify(json));
            alert('Saved to localStorage');
        });
        //  }
        // }
    };
}
initMap();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't spend a lot of time to read your code and I didn't get the point of using two layers instead of one layer. With some `console.log()` statements I realized that you are always saving `drawLayer` to `localStorage` and that's why you miss saved/updated data.

I forked your jsfiddle **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/488dyz6u/1/)** and did small modifications in `savePolygons()` method and seems that it is working now as expected.

In short words I make sure that I'm saving the data from `drawLayer` and `savedLayer` to `localStorage` so we don't miss anything.

Just for reference:

```
function savePolygons(json) {
    var btn = document.getElementById('save-edits');
    btn.onclick = function() {

        var drawLayerData, savedLayerData;

        drawLayer.toGeoJson(function(json) {

            console.log('saving geo data drawLayer ...')
            console.log(json);
            drawLayerData = json;

            if(typeof savedLayerData != 'undefined'){
                json.features = json.features.concat(savedLayerData.features)
                localStorage.setItem('geoData', JSON.stringify(json));
                alert('Data was saved');
            }
        });

        savedLayer.toGeoJson(function(json) {

            console.log('saving geo data savedLayer ...')
            console.log(json);
            savedLayerData = json;

            if(typeof drawLayerData != 'undefined'){
                json.features = json.features.concat(drawLayerData.features)
                localStorage.setItem('geoData', JSON.stringify(json));
                alert('Data was saved');
            }
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks sand. I'm testing this. But isn't this replacing the entire collection instead of replacing the one polygon that was edited?

Comment: @mapr this code is always updating the `localStorage` with latest data from `drawLayer` and `savedLayer`, so yes it is replacing the entire collection, but isn't it working as you want ? I can add new stuff, change old stuff and when I save I see exactly what I saved - isn't this the point ?

Comment: Yes it's working well. But if one is storing these in a database, and if you have drawn 50-100 polygons, isn't it expensive to send the entire collection rather than the one that was just edited?

Comment: Well this question is a matter of database design, if you store whole object `json` in MySQL `TEXT` field you will be fine to always overwrite this field with the latest data ( people are sending much more bigger objects over HTTP ). Well if you have a single row for each polygon then you can send only `drawLayer` to your server. Possibilities are a lot, as I said this is another story :) Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts @sand. Appreciated.